# Raw string notation in regular expressions

Tags: python, regex

Python has this way of specifying regular expression pattern, where all special character should not be treated as special. From the docs:

> So r"\n" is a two-character string containing '\' and 'n', while "\n" is a one-character string containing a newline.

Why then does this works?

```
import re
print re.split(r"\n", "1\n2\n3")
```

The first argument should be "\" and "n" and the second one should contain two newlines. But it prints:

```
['1', '2', '3']
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first one does contain backslash-and-n, but in regular-expression-language, backslash-and-n means newline (just like it does in Python string syntax).  That is, the string `r"\n"` does not contain an actual newline, but it contains something that tells the regular expression engine to look for actual newlines.

If you want to search for a backslash followed by n, you need to use `r"\\n"`.

The point of the raw strings is that they block Python's basic intepretation of string escapes, allowing you to use the backslash for its regular-expression meaning.  If you don't want the regular-expression meaning, you still have to use two backslashes, as in my example above.  But without raw strings it would be even worse: if you wanted to search for literal backslash-n without a raw string, you'd have to use `"\\\\n"`.  If the raw string blocked interpretation of the regular expression special characters (so that plain `"\n"` really meant backslash-n), you wouldn't have any way of using the regular expression syntax at all.

Comment: Hmm...and how do I search for "\" followed by "n"?

Comment: @BrenBarn It's been some time since you answered this but I hope someone could help. I tried to match a backslash followed by n (`text='\\n'`)and I do `re.match(r'\\n',text)`. The result is `<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 2), match='\\n'>` . Why would i get \\n in instead of \n?

Comment: @Le0: The string `'\\n'` represent a backslash followed by `n`, just as it does in your `text` string.  If you don't understand what's going on, look up many other questions on here about extra backslashes, raw strings, etc.  If you still don't understand, post a separate question rather than asking in a comment.